# Convert XLS file to CSV file in perl without using spreadsheet

Tags: perl, csv, text-formatting

I have a file in [.XLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLS) format and I want to load that file on [Informatica](https://www.informatica.com), for which I need to convert that file to [.CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), i.e. XLS to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Install [perl](https://learn.perl.org/installing/unix_linux.html) if not already installed, then execute a script [xls2csv](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/KEN/xls2csv-1.06/script/xls2csv) with a command similar to:

```
xls2csv -x "source.xls" -c "destination.csv"
```